# What are my options for dependent variable as percentage of quality?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, predictive-models, model, feature-engineering

First of all, thanks for taking your time to answer me.
I'm aware that this can be a self-study question and I wanted to make it as generic as possible so other people could also benefit from it

In my problem I have:

- A set of numerical independent features (X)
- One dependent variable which represents a percentage of quality between 0 and 1 (Y)

I have a training dataset with different values of features, and the quality as output. Let's say that I want to obtain the best feature (X1) that maximises the quality (Y) by keeping the other features constant.

What approaches do you recommend to follow? For the modelling, I was thinking about Logistic Regression but that would be for binary classes. I could create a threshold in the percentage of quality, for example <0.7 = 0 and >=0.7 = 1 but that would limit the problem and the parameter that I want to obtain wouldn't be very accurate in my opinion.

Once I have the model, I can iterate different values of the feature (X1) until I maximise the quality, but my doubt is in how can I model this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to reduce the dimension of your problem. This can be done using the singular value decomposition if you have gradient information. If you don't have gradients, we can still reduce the dimension of your problem. Say you have a vector of observations $Y$ and a matrix of associated inputs $X$. Let $Xa=Y$ and solve for $a$. This linear model will produce a set of weights of how "important" each input is. We can now construct a new reduced dimension variable,

$z_j=\frac{\sum a_i x_{ij}}{\sum a_i}$.

This is a linear active subspace model. A quadratic active subspace can give you multiple reduced variables and a metric describing their relative contribution to the system. Here is a tutorial with more information in case you are interested: https://github.com/paulcon/active_subspaces/blob/master/tutorials/basic.ipynb

If you really do want to identify which already-defined input contributes the most to your signal, you have to define what sensitivity means to you. There are several metrics available, and problem-specific information is what gives them meaning. Common sensitivity metrics are the average gradient estimated using finite differences across the function space, the contribution of an input's variability to the variance of the output, and the $a$ weights I described earlier. One common approach to estimating the average gradient in each input dimension is called Elementary Effects. The analysis of variance is usually called ANOVA or sobol indexes.